# A qualified problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=W\bigoplus W^{\bot}$ and $T:V\longrightarrow W$ the corresponding projection. Using the definition of adjoint $T^{*}$ to show $T^{*}=T$.

Comment: When you say "Qualified problem", I assume this is taken from a past qualifying exam. May I know the source? (I would be interested in practising)

Comment: http://www.mtu.edu/math/graduate/masters/qualifying-exam/

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: So let $v_1, v_2 \in V$. Write $v_i = w_i + w_i'$ with $w_i \in W$, $w_i'\in W^\bot$. We have to prove 
$$ (Tv_1, v_2) = (v_1, Tv_2) $$
Just compute both sides using $Tv_i = w_i$ and $(w_i, w_j') = 0$ as $W \perp W^\perp$.